# Unite GIS areas within R (e.g., counties into core based statistical areas)

Tags: r, gis

I have a shapefile with US counties that I read into r with `readOGR()`. I need to combine the 3,000 US counties into larger areas, for example the 929 Core Based Statistical Areas ([the NBER](https://www.nber.org/data/cbsa-fips-county-crosswalk.html) provides a crosswalk from county FIPS to it). In graphic design, this would be a union of shapes. Can I do this programmatically within `R` without using a Geographic Information System?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the function `ms_dissolve()` from [`rmapshaper`](https://rdrr.io/cran/rmapshaper/man/ms_dissolve.html). For example, to unite the shapes of counties into states:

```
library(rmapshaper)

# Download the shapefile for US counties from here and save in some/dir
# www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2010/gz_2010_us_050_00_5m.zip
counties <- readOGR(dsn="some/dir",layer="gz_2010_us_050_00_5m")

# Drop Alaska, hawaii, Puerto Rico
counties <- counties[!(counties$STATE %in% c("02","15","72")), ]

# Plot counties
plot(counties)

# Unite shapes
library(rmapshaper)
states <- ms_dissolve(counties, field = "STATE")

plot(states)
```

Map of counties:
[image: map of counties]

Map of states from the union of counties:
[image: Map of states from the union of counties]

Comment: this works, yes! Can I edit your answer to provide a complete code sample?

Comment: Great! yes, no problem!

Answer (score 0):

The [st_union](https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/reference/geos_combine.html) function in the sf package might be what you're looking for. sf ('simple features') makes working with spatial data much much easier than if you were using QGIS or ArcGis.

Comment: your link says that it works for one polygon as output: "Combine several feature geometries into one, without unioning or resolving internal boundaries". I want multiple polygons as output, so I didn't try it.